# How to fix,code doesnt wait until webdriver find element and procceed with next line of code = error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm working on a program which connects to web and upload + download lot of files, but after I run without `time.sleep()` it ends with an error.

I tried to change to find another element, but I don't want to do it with `time.sleep()` function because not all files are too big.

```
for z in prevadzka:
basepath = path_ + z + '\\'
file_x = [fn for fn in os.listdir(basepath) if fnmatch.fnmatch(fn, 'P???????.*')]
fin_nazov = 0
for x in file_x:
    # upload button
    file_upload = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,xpath_upload)))
    file_upload.send_keys(os.path.abspath(basepath + x))

    overit = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_overit)))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_overit).click()
    #time.sleep(10)
    prevziat = WebDriverWait(driver,300).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_prevziat)))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_prevziat).click()
    #prevziat.click() 
    time.sleep(2.5) # time for download file
    driver.get(link)
driver.close()
```

I expect code to wait until download button shows up (it doesn't)
and then proceed with other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out, i needed add '\a' after copied XPATH so the python know its a link to wait for.

```
'//*[@id="A5540:j_idt30:downloadLink"]/a'
```

instead of

```
'//*[@id="A5540:j_idt30:downloadLink"]'

prevziat = WebDriverWait(driver,300).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_prevziat + '\a')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_prevziat).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absolute majority of cases downloading files using browser automation is not efficient, if your `xpath_prevziat` locator matches [`<a>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) you could get its [href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) attribute via [WebElement.get_attribute()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) function and perform the [file download by Python means](https://stackabuse.com/download-files-with-python/), for example using [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(prevziat.get_attribute('href'), prevziat.text)
```

If the site assumes authentication you could get [cookies](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) from the browser via [WebDriver.get_cookies()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_cookies) function  and [add them to the urllib request](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/73735/urllib.request.add_header)

Comment: thank you for your answer but my xpath refer to element and to 'downloadlink' not to specific href
`xpath_prevziat = '//*[@id="A5540:j_idt23:downloadLink"]'`